# Send files into multiple hosts

Tags: linux, bash

The following down here is my script, the For loop works. Perfectly.
What is not working, is taking hostnames and doing the "SendFiles" loop in all of them. 
Any idea how i could fix this that it would take hostnames from Phy_Hosts variable.

Right now, all it does is repeats it 7 times in `vmfarm1` host.
Might it also be that i have to use `#!/usr/bin/env bash` enviourment?

```
#!/bin/bash
#Location where bash scripts are located.

phy_ssh=/opt/wiki_scripts/servers.sh 
vm_ssh=/opt/wiki_scripts/virtualservers.sh

#Hosts where we will ssh into.
Phy_Hosts=(vmfarm1 p12 barclay maximus backupfirefly accountant 10.6.6.90)

SendFiles () {
        host=$1
        ssh root@${Phy_Hosts} 'bash -s' < ${phy_ssh}
        ssh root@${Phy_Hosts} cat /root/phy_machines.txt >>  /opt/wiki_scripts/phy_machines.txt
}

hostCount=${#Phy_Hosts[@]}

# backup databases
for ((i=0; i<${hostCount}; i++))
do
        host=${Phy_Hosts[$i]}
        SendFiles ${host}
done

exit 0
```

---

EDIT:

```
Currently:

#!/bin/bash
# Location where bash scripts are located.
phy_ssh=/opt/wiki_scripts/servers.sh 
vm_ssh=/opt/wiki_scripts/virtualservers.sh

# Hosts where we will ssh into.
Phy_Hosts=( vmfarm1 p12 barclay maximus backup firefly accountant 10.6.6.90 )

vmfarm1=( icinga ldap mail openvpn dns redmine owncloud www git)

maximus=( elasticsearch jenkins egcut demo )
firefly=( client )
texta=( live 10.6.6.92 10.6.6.93 )

SendFiles () {
        local host="$1"
        ssh "root@$host" 'bash -s' <"$phy_ssh"
        ssh "root@$host" cat /root/phy_machines.txt
}

SendFiles1 () {
        local host1="$1"
        ssh "root@$host1" 'bash -s' <"$vm_ssh"
        ssh "root@$host1" cat /root/vm_machines.txt
}


# Save the following data to the phy_machine file.
for host in "${Phy_Hosts[@]}"; do
        SendFiles "$host"
done >>/opt/wiki_scripts/phy_machines.txt

# Save the following data to the vm_machine file.
for host1 in "${vmfarm1[@]}"; do
        SendFiles1 "$host1"
done >>/opt/wiki_scripts/vm_machines.txt

# Save the following data to the vm_machine file.
for host1 in "${maximus[@]}"; do
        SendFiles1 "$host1"
done >>/opt/wiki_scripts/vm_machines.txt

# Save the following data to the vm_machine file.
for host1 in "${firefly[@]}"; do
        SendFiles1 "$host1"
done >>/opt/wiki_scripts/vm_machines.txt

# Save the following data to the vm_machine file.
for host1 in "${texta[@]}"; do
        SendFiles1 "$host1"
done >>/opt/wiki_scripts/vm_machines.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Location where bash scripts are located.
phy_ssh=/opt/wiki_scripts/servers.sh 

# Hosts where we will ssh into.
Phy_Hosts=( vmfarm1 p12 barclay maximus backupfirefly accountant 10.6.6.90 )

SendFiles () {
        local host="$1"
        ssh "root@$host" 'bash -s' <"$phy_ssh"
        ssh "root@$host" cat /root/phy_machines.txt
}

# backup databases
for host in "${Phy_Hosts[@]}"; do
        SendFiles "$host"
done >/opt/wiki_scripts/phy_machines.txt
```

- The looping can be done over the array directly, no need to use indexing.
- You never used the `host` variable in the function.
- General clean-up, including removing unused variable `vm_ssh`, double quoting variable expansions, and removing the unneeded `exit 0` at the end.
- Redirection of output moved from within the function to the `for` loop. This may not be necessary, or may indeed be the wrong thing to do if you expect the first `ssh` call in the function to output something, but it makes the function cleaner.

---

After a few iterations of comments:

Only define the `SendFiles` function once (later definitions of it will override the earlier).  Let it take *all* information that it needs to run for any particular set of hosts.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Location where bash scripts are located.
phy_ssh=/opt/wiki_scripts/servers.sh
vm_ssh=/opt/wiki_scripts/virtualservers.sh
others_ssh=/opt/wiki_scripts/others.sh

# Hosts where we will ssh into.
Phy_Hosts=( vmfarm1 p12 barclay maximus backupfirefly accountant 10.6.6.90 )
Vm_Hosts=( icinga.stacc.ee ldap.stacc.ee mail.stacc.ee openvpn.stacc.ee dns.stacc.ee redmine.stacc.ee owncloud.stacc.ee www.stacc.ee git.stacc.ee )
SomeOther_list ( more machines )

SendFiles () {
        local host="$1"
        local script="$2"
        local remotefile="$3"

        ssh "root@$host" 'bash -s' <"$script"
        ssh "root@$host" cat "$remotefile"
}

# backup databases
for host in "${Phy_Hosts[@]}"; do
        SendFiles "$host" "$phy_ssh" /root/phy_machines.txt
done >/opt/wiki_scripts/phy_machines.txt

for host in "${Vm_Hosts[@]}"; do
        SendFiles "$host" "$vm_ssh" /root/vm_machines.txt
done >/opt/wiki_scripts/vm_machines.txt

# and then, for example
for host in "${SomeOther_list[@]}"; do
        SendFiles "$host" "$others_ssh" /root/other_machines.txt
done >/opt/wiki_scripts/other_machines.txt
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75134/discussion-on-answer-by-kusalananda-send-files-into-multiple-hosts).